# When to use row operation or cofactor method to find matrix inverse?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I find two different answers by using these two methods in a same matrix.
How can I decide to use row operation or cofactor method?

Comment: Note that it is easy to check: multiply your inverse by the original matrix, if you get the identity matrix then your inverse is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should end in the same answer. For some matrices one method is easier than the other though. It is up to you to decide which you'd rather use. If your teacher/professor specifies a certain way do that.

The inverse of a matrix is unique so if you get different answers with different methods that means you did something wrong in one or both of them.